# Display prepopulated value in mat auto select input box, with Code as value and name in input text

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete

general.component.html :

```
     <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{iTitle}}</mat-label>
     <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="iCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
     [required]="required" />
     <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let op of filteredOptions | async" [value]="op.code">
    {{ op.name }} 
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

general.component.ts:

```
ngOnChanges() {

  if (this.options?.length && !this.filteredOptions) {
      this.filteredOptions = this.iCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((value) =>this.filterName(value))
      )
    }
    this.options.forEach((op) => {
      (this.dataMapping[op.code|| ''] = op.name|| '')
    })
  }
}

if (this.formGroup && !this.formGroup.get(this.fieldName)) {
  this.formGroup.setControl(this.fieldName, this.iCtrl)
}
}
displayFn(event):string {
  return this.dataMapping[event]
 }

  selectedSource(event): string {
  const code= event
  return this.dataMapping[code] 
 }

  private filterWithDescription(data: string): newData[] {
  if (!data|| !this.options?.length) {
    return this.options
   }
  const filterValue = data.toLowerCase()
 return this.options.filter((op) =>
   op.name?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))
}
}
```

In the above code I am trying to set default value or prepopulated value in the input box, but I am able to see only the code not name. I tried using `.find()` to find the values from `this.options` and return the value in `displayFn` but t`his.options` inside `displayFn` returns `undefined`, hence `dataMapping` also doesn't work.  At `ngOnchanges` I am setting the value of the `formgroup`,

```
            this.formGroup.setControl(this.fieldName, this.iCtrl)
```

is it any other way this can be handled.